# Strange javascript toString() behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

I'm trying to use toString to temporarily output a class to the DOM.
I'm getting some behaviour I don't understand where the overriden `toString()` will always output the initial state. However, if an external function is used (i.e. stateToString) or even `JSON.stringify`, the updated state is outputted as I would expect.

Below is my attempt to minimally reproduce this behaviour.
To reiterate, my expected behaviour is for all of them to initially output: `["initial"]`, which they do. However, the `toString()` output does not update when the button is clicked but the other two do.

This seems particularly strange as `stateToString` and `State.toString` seem to be essentially identical functions, except one takes state as a receiver and one takes state as a parameter.

I'd appreciate if someone could explain why this behaviour occurs.

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

class State { 
  constructor(xs) { this.xs = xs } 
  toString = () => `[${this.xs}]`
}

const stateToString = state => `[${state.xs}]`;

const reducer = (state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  xs: [...state.xs, action.x]
});

const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, new State(["initial"]));
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ x: Math.random() })}>click</button><br />
      toString:  {state.toString()}<br />
      print:     {stateToString(state)}<br />
      stringify: {JSON.stringify(state)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4):

The `toString` method you put on the State is bound to the *original instance* of the state:

```
class State { 
  constructor(xs) { this.xs = xs } 
  toString = () => `[${this.xs}]` // Class field arrow function
}
```

The class field there means that no matter what calling context the `toString` is called with, it will return the `this.xs` of the initial State. Even if the reducer updates the state, the state's constructor *does not run again*.

On later calls of `App`, the initial state is created, and then goes through some actions to update it, resulting in the `state` variable being an updated object, *but it still has a `toString` method bound to the initial state*.

Here's an example of the behavior in vanilla JS:

```js
const obj = {
  val: 'val',
  toString: () => obj.val
};

const copiedObj = { ...obj, val: 'newVal' };
console.log(copiedObj.toString());
```

If you assigned a `function` rather than an arrow function, then the `toString` would be called with a calling context of the *updated* state, because it's not bound to the initial state, so it'll be called with a calling context of the updated state and properly retrieve the `xs`:

```
toString = function () {
    return `[${this.xs}]`;
}
```

As a side note, you can't use an ordinary *method* like

```
toString() {
    return `[${this.xs}]`;
}
```

because in your reducer:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    xs: [...state.xs, action.x]
});
```

spread syntax only takes *enumerable own* properties. With *method* syntax (like `toString() {`), the property is put on the State *prototype*, not the actual instance, so it won't exist in the final `state`, and the built-in `Object.prototype.toString` will be invoked instead.